# complex Analysis integration.

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know How to go about it but I have got a test on it most especially how they got $\pi$ into the answer. [![enter image description here][1]][1]
question 9 and 10
if $f(z) =8z^2-2/z(z-1)(z+1)$ evaluate close integral of $f(z) dz$ along the contour $c$ where $c$ is a triangle  joining the points $z=2 ,z=j , z=-1-j$

  1.

Comment: Your question isn't clear and you seem to have forgotten the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the Residue Theorem? The poles are at $0,1,-1$ and $-1$ is outside the triangle. The residues at $0$ and $1$ are $2$ and $3$ so the answer is $2\pi i (2+3)=10\pi i$.

Comment: yea will be reading about it